# Highcharts overlapping and stacked column

Tags: javascript, highcharts

How can I do a chart with overlapping and stacking columns?

I tried to do it with two axis, but I need both axis to be equals. 
The max value of each axis will change lot of times, so I cannot set a max value for them.

How can i set both axis to be equals, or how can i do the chart with only 1 axis ??

```
 $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: { type: 'column' },
    yAxis: [{
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Employees'
        }
    }, {
        title: {
            text: 'Profit (millions)'
        },
        opposite: true
    }],
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            grouping: false,
            shadow: false,
            borderWidth: 0
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Employees',
        data: [150, 73, 80],
        pointPadding: 0.1
    },{
        name: 'Profit',
        data: [183.6, 178.8, 198.5],
        pointPadding: 0.1
    }, 

             {
        name: 'Employees Optimized',
        data: [440, 90, 40],
        pointPadding: 0.4,
        yAxis: 1
    },  {
        name: 'Profit Optimized',
        data: [203.6, 198.8, 208.5],
        pointPadding: 0.4,
        yAxis:1
    }]
});
```

[image: Example]

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chofer/3u4t2pLy/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set multiple [`stack`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series<column>.stack)s and use a single `yAxis` for all series. Additionally you can also keep second `yAxis` that will be linked to the one that is used by all series, but placed on another side of the plot area.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aejr2L6e/